# Kotlin Flow - Code not being executed inside collect block in view model

Tags: android, kotlin, viewmodel, coroutine, kotlin-flow

I don't understand why collect block not being executed, usually this is not an issue in my earlier projects. Actually the function is run well, just I cannot collect the result.

ViewModel.

```
fun sendOtp(activity: Activity) {
        viewModelScope.launch {
            Timber.tag("View Model - Outside Collect").i("Outside Collect")
            authUseCase.sendOtp(activity, _authState.value.phoneNumber).collect { result ->
                Timber.tag("View Model - Inside Collect").i("$result")
                when (result) {
                    is Resource.Success -> {
                        Timber.tag("VIEW MODEL - SUCCESS").i("${result.message} | ${result.data}")
                    }

                    is Resource.Error -> {
                        Timber.tag("VIEW MODEL - ERROR").e("${result.message} | ${result.data}")
                    }

                    is Resource.Loading -> {
                        Timber.tag("VIEW MODEL - LOADING").d("${result.message} | ${result.data}")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is my use case.

```
class SendOtpImpl @Inject constructor(
    private val authRepository: AuthRepository
): SendOtp {
    override operator fun invoke(activity: Activity, phoneNumber: String): Flow<Resource<String>> = flow {
        authRepository.sendOtp(activity, phoneNumber).onStart {
            emit(Resource.Loading("OTP Code will be sent to +$phoneNumber"))
        }.collect()
    }
}
```

Also my repository.

```
override fun sendOtp(activity: Activity, phoneNumber: String): Flow<Resource<String>> = flow {
        val options = _authBuilder
            .setActivity(activity)
            .setPhoneNumber("$phoneNumber")
            .build()

        PhoneAuthProvider.verifyPhoneNumber(options)
        emit(_callbacksState.value)
        Timber.tag("Repository").d("${_callbacksState.value.data}")
    }
```

Thanks for your time...

I already Log it, and it only run this.

[image]

On the other hand, I try other way to collect flow like this, but the result is still same.

```
authUseCase.authUseCase.sendOtp(activity, _authState.value.phoneNumber).onEach { result ->
            when (result) {
                is Resource.Success -> {
                    Timber.tag("VIEW MODEL VERIFY - SUCCESS").i("${result.message} | ${result.data}")
                }
                is Resource.Error -> {
                    Timber.tag("VIEW MODEL VERIFY - ERROR").e("${result.message} | ${result.data}")
                }
                is Resource.Loading -> {
                    Timber.tag("VIEW MODEL VERIFY - LOADING").d("${result.message} | ${result.data}")
                }
            }
        }.launchIn(viewModelScope)
```

Comment: For me there are 2 strange parts in the code. 1. In the use case you collect the flow from the repository. That means `invoke()` can return only after the flow is fully consumed. Is this your expected behavior? I think this is the root cause of your problem, it's a kind of deadlock. 2. Flow in the repository simply takes the current value and immediately finishes. Again, is this expected?

Comment: If your idea in the use case was to "inject" additional item at the beginning of the flow, then you should simply return the result of `onStart()`, instead of collecting it and creating another flow.

Comment: Thank you so much! Your solution worked like a charm. I was struggling with this problem for a while, and your explanation made it crystal clear.